# Comparing 2 string values, not working!?

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare two string values that was retrieved in my first function, but it doesn't work. It keeps telling me 'invalid syntax' and moves my cursor over to the elif line.

This is my program...

```
def find_number_of_service():
    with open('TheData.txt', 'r') as data_file:
        data = data_file.read()

    countS = data.count('S')
    countW = data.count('W')

    print ("There are " + str(countS) + " S's")
    print ("There are " + str(countW) + " W's")
    return


def find_popular_service():
    if (countS) > (countW):
        print ("The most used service to buy tickets was the school.")
        elif print ("The most used service to buy tickets was the website.")

        return

#Main program
find_number_of_service()
find_popular_service()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have too many errors to mention. Your indentation is off, you used elif without a condition and colons, you did not define countS and countW in your function and so on.

Comment: I'd suggest to refine your question, to be more speicif, and to keep only the information needed - this way you'll get the answer faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in second function `elif` you have not defined correctly it should be `elif <condition>:`

Here the working function

```
def find_popular_service():
    if (countS) > (countW):
        print ("The most used service to buy tickets was the school.")
    else:
        print ("The most used service to buy tickets was the website.")
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

- You don't give `elif` a condition.  `elif` means `otherwise if...`.  Perhaps you mean `else`.
- `elif` should be in line with `if`
- `print ...` should be on a new line.